# What exactly goes into implementing a file format?

Tags: implementation, file-format

While fully aware of the possibility that the main reason for me being unable to find a clear, coherent answer to this question somewhere on the internet is that the question itself may be extraordinarily misguided and naive, I still have to make a last desperate attempt and ask in here for a clarification.

So I get that file formats in themselves are nothing but an arbitrary way of storing data and, in a sense, a general agreement between the individuals who do wanna use the format that this is how the data must be encoded and decoded, but what I would like to know is how exactly does the computer recognize it, agree with it and know what to do with it so that at the end of the day you can have your output, in whatever form that may be, and also how do people handle the implementation for that. I really don't care about the specific intricacies of how the data is stored (such as RGB and Alpha channels for image file formats) or how is the output produced at a hardware level, more like what bridges the two. My best guess after giving it some thought would be that it's up to the software, but I don't know, seems odd, having an arbitrary way of storing data just for each program to now have an arbitrary way of communicating it to the hardware.

I don't know the level of generality to this question, I expect it to be low, so I don't mind an explanation based on a specific type of data (images, audios, documents etc.) and I was technically thinking of image formats at first, but bare in mind, it doesn't matter that much, this is mostly a question raised out of pure inquisitiveness and I doubt I'll get away with any particularly practical piece of new acquired information as a result of it. Might've formulated the whole thing in an overly long and complicated manner but I really wanted to make sure that I get my message across this time around, trying to google this proved itself to be a fruitless endeavor.

Comment: *"how exactly does the computer recognize it, agree with it and know what to do with it"* - by explicitly telling the computer how to parse and work with e.g. a docx file or a zip archive. Writing a program to work the file is basically part of coming up with the format. If you have to program being able to read and interpret the file then your format has no purpose.

Comment: "How does a piece of paper recognize the English language and know what to do with it?" It doesn't. The person reading the paper is the one that recognizes it and knows what to do. In this case the "person" is the computer program, not the computer.